# iOS app build - Error with authentication

Tags: ios, xcode, build

When we try to build our application (React Native) for iOS using Fastlane, following error is thrown out. Any idea what causes it?

We can use the same apple ID used in that iMac to login to other apple services like appstoreconnect or iCloud and it uses 2FA.

```
[01:24:57]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ProntoPoc.xcworkspace -scheme ProntoPoc -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/mobileappbuilder/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-12-19/ProntoPoc\ 2022-12-19\ 01.24.57.xcarchive archive | tee /Users/mobileappbuilder/Library/Logs/gym/ProntoPoc-ProntoPoc.log | xcpretty
^C[01:25:04]: ▸ 2022-12-19 01:25:04.095 xcodebuild[1052:13667]  DVTPortal: Service '<DVTPortalViewDeveloperService: 0x600003a88140; action='viewDeveloper'>' encountered an unexpected result code from the portal ('1100')
[01:25:04]: ▸ 2022-12-19 01:25:04.095 xcodebuild[1052:13667]  DVTPortal: Error:
[01:25:04]: ▸ Error Domain=DVTPortalServiceErrorDomain Code=1100 "Your session has expired. Please log in." UserInfo={payload={
[01:25:04]: ▸     creationTimestamp = "2022-12-18T14:25:04Z";
[01:25:04]: ▸     httpCode = 200;
[01:25:04]: ▸     protocolVersion = QH65B2;
[01:25:04]: ▸     requestUrl = "https://developerservices2.apple.com/services/QH65B2/viewDeveloper.action";
[01:25:04]: ▸     responseId = "1d45c6a2-d006-4f63-804f-60ae07bdf8da";
[01:25:04]: ▸     resultCode = 1100;
[01:25:04]: ▸     resultString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
[01:25:04]: ▸     userLocale = "en_US";
[01:25:04]: ▸     userString = "Your session has expired. Please log in.";
[01:25:04]: ▸ }, NSLocalizedDescription=Your session has expired. Please log in.}
```

We tried restarting the mac, removing and re-adding the apple id in xcode and in the Mac itself. Archiving and verifying works fine through xcode but we need this to taken in CI/CD scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved via Apple forum. Check the follwing
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254476654?login=true